# What should I do if the restlet server timeout?

Tags: java, timeout, restlet

I use restlet2.2+eclipse+tomcat to deploy my webservice, but the method of @Get needs a lot of time to perform.When I put the URL in the explorer, after a period of time, the explorer cant't reponse due to timeout.What should I do

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the HTTP connector you are using, you can configure properties to increase the socket timeout. Check the Javadocs of the HttpServerHelper classes (Jetty / Simple extensions) for guidance.